# Adding/Changing variable name with an int or string in Java

Tags: java, arrays, variables

I'm new to Java so I'm sure my code is abysmal in comparison to cleaner/organized code.

Link to full code: http://pastebin.com/UXJzU2ax

What it looks like when ran.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gfUk.png)

I'm attempting to add a number onto the end of a variable via a number in an array. I'm unsure as to how this can be achieved.

I have created a 10x10 grid of buttons with randomly generated colors, I wish to change the adjacent buttons color on click, but only if the color is the same.

Color generation.

```
int[] squares;

        squares = new int[101];

        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++){

            squares[i] = i;
            JButton button = new JButton("" + squares[i]);


            int color = (int) (Math.random() * 4); //rand 1 to 4

            if (color == 1){

                button.setBackground(Color.red);

            } else if (color == 2){

                button.setBackground(Color.green);

            } else if (color == 3){

                button.setBackground(Color.yellow);

            } else {

                button.setBackground(Color.blue);

            } 
            button.setName("button" + (Integer.toString(squares[i])));
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()

            {
```

My way of knowing where directions are.

```
right = Integer.parseInt(button.getText()) + 1;
                        up = Integer.parseInt(button.getText()) - 10;
                        down = Integer.parseInt(button.getText()) + 10;

                        right2 = squares[right];
                        up2 = squares[up];
                        down2 = squares[down];
```

This is where I'm running into troubles.

```
if (btnSelectedColor.getBackground() == button.getBackground()){

                            //Where I need the change in "button", like "button[right].getBackground", or something similar.

                            if (button.getBackground() == btnSelectedColor.getBackground()){



                            }

                        }
```

Comment: How are you storing your buttons? An array? A list? Or Maybe the issue is that you are not.

Comment: This maybe?
"squares[i] = i;
   JButton button = new JButton("" + squares[i]);"

Comment: Well, I suppose the buttons are being added to the JPanel. So maybe you can access them from the JPanel. If not, then you need some data structure of your own to hold the buttons so that you can access the neighbor buttons.

Comment: The problem is, that all buttons names are generated accordingly when the program is RAN, so I'm assuming I can't refer back to them when they technically don't exist in the code? Or at least do something like "button(right).getBackground"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can access the other buttons.

**Note**: I will not write all the logic here. I will leave the method of getting the neighbors to you.

In the `actionPerformed` callback, you need somehting like this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    // get all components of the panel
    Component[] comp = panel.getComponents();

    // loop through all components
    for (int i = 0; i < comp.length; i++)
    {
        // if it's a button...
        if (comp[i] instanceof JButton)
        {
            JButton b = (JButton) comp[i];

            // if b is a neighbor of button (e.g. the one clicked),
            // then change its background color
            // I leave this logic to you (seems like you wrote most if it already)

            // Hint: Convert the text of b to an int and convert the
            // text of button to an int and compare the ints to see if 
            // they are neighbors. You can convert the int of 
            // button.getText once outside of the loop. No sense in 
            // doing the conversion every time since it will be the same.
        }

    }

    // Rest of code in your actionPerformed method...

}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would extend JButton

> public class BuddyButton extends JButton {

The new BuddyButton would have 4 fields

> private BuddyButton north;
>     private BuddyButton south;
>     private BuddyButton east;
>     private BuddyButton west;

Initerate buttons[][]

```
BuddyButton buttons[][] = new BuddyButton[10][10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        BuddyButton buddy = new BuddyButton();
        buttons[i][j] = buddy;
        panel.add(buddy);
        buddy.addActionListener(listener);;
    }
}
```

Loop through buttons[][] again linking all the BuddyButtons

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        BuddyButton buddy = new BuddyButton();
        buttons[i][j] = buddy;
        panel.add(buddy);
        buddy.addActionListener(listener);
    }
}

public static void linkBuddies(int i, int j) {
    if (i > 0)
        buttons[i][j].setNorth(buttons[i - 1][j]);
    if (i < 10)
        buttons[i][j].setSouth(buttons[i + 1][j]);
    if (j > 0)
        buttons[i][j].setWest(buttons[i + 1][j - 1]);
    if (j > 10)
        buttons[i][j].setEast(buttons[i + 1][j + 1]);       
}
```

When a BuddyButton is clicked cast e.getSource() back to a BuddyButton

```
listener = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        BuddyButton buddy = (BuddyButton) e.getSource();
        BuddyButton north = buddy.getNorth();
        BuddyButton south = buddy.getSouth();
        BuddyButton east = buddy.getEast();
        BuddyButton west = buddy.getWest();
//Check for nulls and talk to the neighbors!!!!
    }};
```